# Getting Facebook data after FacebookUtils.logIn

Tags: facebook, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.FacebookUtils to authenticate users with Facebook, doing the following:

```
const user = await Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn('public_profile,email')
```

The object received back only contains the user's FacebookId and an access_token inside `authData.facebook`.
How am I supposed to get the actual user's data during authentication? I'd like the object coming back to include the data specified in the scope passed (name, email, picture).

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to permission requirements. For example, the way I login with Facebook and retrieve user info is:

1. Request permission with Login:

   let permissions = ["public_profile", "email"]

   PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackground(withReadPermissions: permissions)
2. Make a Graph request with parameters (fields) you are looking to retrieve:

   ```
   let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters:["fields": 
   "email"])
   let connection = FBSDKGraphRequestConnection()
   connection.timeout = 30
   connection.add(graphRequest, completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in

       if error != nil {

           print(error ?? "error")

       } else if let res = result as! NSDictionary? {

           print(res)
       }
    })

    connection.start()
   ```

When you make the graph request after successfully requesting permission and logging in, you will receive the parameters specified in the Graph request in JSON format.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks I'll try to look at how to add a graph request w the JS sdk. No official documentation about that...